# React Native HeadlessJS Geolocation not working

Tags: java, android, react-native, geolocation, background-process

I have installed react-native-geolocation-service and got it to work, but my headless version doesn't log any messages.

```
//LocationService.java
package com.myApp.service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
//creating the service class
public class LocationService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    @Override
    protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "LocationService", //JS function to call
                Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
                5000, // timeout for the task
                true
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
//MainApplication.java
...
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.Location;
import com.myApp.service.LocationService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
...
private final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }
        
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    }
        
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    }
        
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(myIntent);
            
        HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(getApplicationContext());
    }
};

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
        
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, listener); // Start requesting for location
        
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
```

To my understanding, `requestLocationUpdates(..., 2000, 0, ...)` will request an update every 2 seconds, regardless of distance change.

```
//AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<application
...
<service android:name="com.myApp.service.LocationService" />
...
/application>
```

```
//LocationService.js
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

module.exports = async (data) => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            console.log(position.coords);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000, forceRequestLocation: true }
    );
}
```

```
//index.js
import LocationService from './src/services/LocationService';
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('LocationService', () => LocationService);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Sorry for the wall of text, but I cannot find where I am going wrong with this headless task. I can manually request my location by calling `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)`, but it should automatically log the location every 2 seconds to my understanding.

Comment: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation

Use This Library

Comment: In Which Device Your Trying To Test?

https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Please Check This Also. Headlesstask will not work especially for Location Services In Killed State. As Devices Now Prefered Batter Optimization.

OS Kill That Service Which Drains Battery.

Comment: I Tried the Same For 3 Hours Of Interval. But not all devices are supported. After Android 8/9 OS Battery Optimization Preference Is More.

I Tested in Xiaomi 6 Pro, 9, and Samusng.

You Might Face Issue In Build, not while Testing because device is attached to charger.

Comment: There 90% of chances that service will be stopped after Device Battery Percent Went Lower Than 60%